# mdfind stops after 50 attempts

Tags: macos, shell, photoshop, extendscript

This is a bizarre problem my team has been having.  We use mdfind to search our archive of images to pull up images, and make a web image for it.

It seems that after roughly 50-60 searches it flat stops searches.
The searches are going out over our network to a Mac server.  The server is running an older OS 10.6.8, we are running 10.10.2.  Authentication is MS Active directory.

The code we use to find the images is ran through extendscript and calls straight to the system:

`system("mdfind -onlyin '/Volumes/photowork/' 'kMDItemDisplayName == \"*" + fullID + "*\"cd' | grep [.] | grep -v 'MERGE\\|MASK\\|REF\\|cof\\|cop' > ~/desktop/product_search.txt")`

(fullID is a variable for the image name we are looking for)

I'm at a loss as to how to attempt to fix this.  I've tried clearing the finder cache, photoshop cache.  Nothing seems to work.  Interestingly enough, spotlight also fails to keep working when looking at this volume after this breaking point happens.  The only work around we have is to disconnect from the volume and reconnect.

Comment: Have you tried running the `mdfind` directly on the server itself? That way you could rule out Extendscript, the client, the difference in OS versions, MS Active Directory and the network...

Comment: I have not done that yet, great idea!  I did just finish a and test a shell script that preforms the same search 100 times.  I had it echo the find into text files with the name of the iteration of the bash loop it was on.  It only made it 75 times before it stopped.  I'll get a hold of my admins and have them run that test.  Thank you Mark!